OutputTransformation on BasicTextField reseting text
Does anyone knows how to properly do a Password OutputTransformation to use with a BasicTextField?
I am doing like this:
                var exibirSenha by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                    BasicTextField (
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                                loginUIState.value.setSenhaInputFocus(focusState.hasFocus)
                            },
                        state = senhaState,
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                        ),
                        onKeyboardAction = { loginViewModel?.login() },
                        outputTransformation = if (!exibirSenha) {
                            SenhaOutputTransformation()
                        } else {
                            null
                        },
                        leftIcon = Icons.Outlined.Lock,
                        rightIcon = if (exibirSenha) Icons.Outlined.VisibilityOff else Icons.Outlined.Visibility,
                        onRightIconClick = {
                            exibirSenha = !exibirSenha
                        }
                    )

And, my SenhaOutputTransformation is like thins:
@Stable
class SenhaOutputTransformation : OutputTransformation {
    companion object {
        private val tag = SenhaOutputTransformation::class.simpleName
        private const val MASCARA_INTERNA = '\u2022'
    }
    override fun TextFieldBuffer.transformOutput() {
        val maskedText = AnnotatedString(MASCARA_INTERNA.toString().repeat(asCharSequence().length))
        replace(0, length, maskedText)
    }
}

But, when i toogle between visible and back to invisible, when i press backspace all text is cleared!

